# testing program with switch case using junit

Tags: java, junit

I want to write test case for calculator program in junit. I am new to junit environment. I can write tests for other programs but kind of stuck with testing for switch() case.

I really want to know how to to do it.

thanks in advance

here is my program

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 //This program performs basic math operations such as :- +,-,*,/
  public class Calculator 

  {      
 public static void main(String[] args) 

 {
     double number1, number2;
     String Mathoperation;
     Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Enter first number");
     number1 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter second number");
     number2 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

     Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("\nHere are your options:");
     System.out.println("\n1. Addition, 2. Subtraction, 3. Divison, 4. Multiplication");
     Mathoperation = UserInput.next();

     switch (Mathoperation)  
     {
       case "1":
       System.out.println("Your answer is " + (number1 + number2));
       break;

       case "2":
       System.out.println("Your answer is " + (number1 - number2));
       break;

       case "3":
       System.out.println("Your answer is " + (number1 / number2));
       break;

       case "4":
       System.out.println("Your asnwer is " + (number1 * number2));
       break;

       default:
       System.out.println("");      
     }   
 }  

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting the input, calculation and output into (non static) methods, which will make testing of the logic possible :

```
//This program performs basic math operations such as :- +,-,*,/
public class Calculator {

    double number1, number2;
    String Mathoperation;

    Calculator()

    {

        //you need to remove input and calculation logic from constructor,
        //to avoid running it when constructing this object for testing.
    }

    public void run() {

        getInput();
        double result = doMath(Mathoperation, number1, number2 );

        System.out.println("Your answer is " + result );
    }

    private void getInput() {

        Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        number1 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        number2 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

        Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nHere are your options:");
        System.out.println("\n1. Addition, 2. Subtraction, 3. Divison, 4. Multiplication");
        Mathoperation = UserInput.next();
    }

    /**
     *@param mathoperation
     */
    public double  doMath(String mathoperation, double number1, double number2) {

        switch (mathoperation)
        {
        case "1":
            return (number1 + number2);

        case "2":
            return  (number1 - number2);

        case "3":
            return (number1 / number2);

        case "4":
            return (number1 * number2);

        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("mathoperation is not valid");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        Calculator calc = new  Calculator();
        calc.run();
    }
}
```

Here is a very simple JUnit test example:

```
public class CalculatorTest {

    /**
     * Test method for {@link Calculator#doMath(java.lang.String, double, double)}.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDoMath() {

        Calculator calc = new Calculator();

        assertTrue(calc.doMath("1", 5, 7) == 12.0);
        assertTrue(calc.doMath("2", 5, 7) == -2.0);
        assertTrue(calc.doMath("3", 5, 7) == (5.0/7.0));
        assertTrue(calc.doMath("4", 5, 7) == (5.0*7.0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mo H. I fixed it. It is always a dilemma for me, should I expose more than needed just for testability.  I usually turn what's need to public for testing, and change it back to private or whatever, after testing.

Comment: @s.p I am glad it helped. If more clarifications are needed feel free to ask. Consider up voting.

Answer (score 5):

The first step to writing unit tests is writing testable code. At this point your code isn't very testable, which is to say you can test it but it won't be the best tests. Lets have a look at why.

The first reason is that you have all your code in your main function. You usually want to avoid this. There are multiple reasons for this, but the two biggest in my opinion are readability and reusability. Normally you would want to put things into different classes, but for the sake of time we will simply put your math switch into its own function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

     //This program performs basic math operations such as :- +,-,*,/
public class Calculator 

{      
 public static void main(String[] args) 

 {
   double number1, number2;
   String Mathoperation;
   Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter first number");
   number1 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Enter second number");
   number2 = scannerObject. nextDouble();

   Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("\nHere are your options:");
   System.out.println("\n1. Addition, 2. Subtraction, 3. Divison, 4. Multiplication");
   Mathoperation = UserInput.next();
   doMath(Mathoperation, number1, number2)
 }

 public double doMath(String Mathoperation, double number1, double number2){
   switch (Mathoperation)  
   {
     case "1":
     System.out.println("Your answer is " + (number1 + number2));
     break;

     case "2":
     System.out.println("Your answer is " + (number1 - number2));
     break;

     case "3":
     System.out.println("Your answer is " + (number1 / number2));
     break;

     case "4":
     System.out.println("Your asnwer is " + (number1 * number2));
     break;

     default:
     System.out.println("");      
   }   
 }
}
```

Ok cool, so now we have our own method for doing our mathematic operations. One issue tho. This isn't a unit in of itself, this is actually an integration between addition and our math operation. What this means is, to test, we would need to test each combination of arithmetic (add, sub, divide, multiply) as well as if the method selects the right operator. Thats alot more work then we want, and isn't a very good test, so how do we fix this? Well simple, we break it down further

```
import java.util.Scanner;

     //This program performs basic math operations such as :- +,-,*,/
public class Calculator {
//Code for use input somewhere here      
 public double doMath(String Mathoperation, double number1, double number2){
   switch (Mathoperation)  
   {
     case "1":
     System.out.println("Your answer is " + add(number1, number2));
     break;

     case "2":
     System.out.println("Your answer is " + sub(number1, number2));
     break;

     case "3":
     System.out.println("Your answer is " + div(number1, number2));
     break;

     case "4":
     System.out.println("Your answer is " + mul(number1, number2));
     break;

     default:
     System.out.println("");      
   }   
 }
 public double add(double number1, double number2){
   return number1 + number2;
 }
 public double sub(double number1, double number2){
   return number1 - number2;
 }
 public double mul(double number1, double number2){
   return number1 * number2;
 }
 public double div(double number1, double number2){
   return number1 / number2;
 }
}
```

Now our units are broken down much more easily. From here you would write test for your `add`, `sub`, `div`, and `mul` functions. Test these out well to insure that they function as expected. Then write tests for the `doMath` function to make sure it passes the values to the right operation. In this way when something fails you know exactly where its failing and what the issue is, as oppose to having to guess. You will know if `doMath` has an issue, or if one of your other math methods is the problem. It also allows you to more easily reuse your methods for other things, so win-win

Answer (score 0):

To write unit tests, you usually have to have pieces of the API that you want to test. In your case, everything is in the main method which gathers user input, so it's hard to test. You should extract something like a `double performOperation(number, number, operation)` method which returns the answer. Then you can write JUnit tests with different inputs to this method.